# JPA EntityGraph: Hibernate attempts to fetch multiple collections in a single query leading to large a Cartesian product

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am using Hibernate behind JPA. I am using EntityGraph to fetch the required data.

I have classes A, B and C

```
class A {
  Integer attrib1;
  String attrib2;
  List<B> blist; // typical size: about 250 objects
  List<C> clist; // typical size about 100 objects
}
```

Classes B and C have their own subgraphs that I am fetching along with the main graph.

The problem is occurring with the main graph.

It is generating 3 SQL queries in all to fetch all the required data.
The problem is with the first query.

In an attempt to reduce the number of queries (that's what I think), in the first query, Hibernate does a join on A, B and C.

i.e

A 
left outer join B on A.x=B.x
left outer join C on A.y=C.y

This creates highly sub-optimal result set with several tens of thousands of rows with a lot a duplicated data across rows.

I can see that the same query can turn out to be very effective by avoiding separate queries for each collection if the number of relations between A and B & A and C is small. However, in this case, since the number of relations is large, it fails miserably.

How do I make hibernate not do this?

I would like Hibernate to generate a separate SQL query for each Collection. This way the cost would go up linearly with collection size.

Comment: But isn't the problem caused exactly by using the EntityGraph. By using entityGraph you explicity ask for all the relationship to be fetched in one query. Ask for only A,B relationship and then Cs will be normally fetched in its own query after lazy loading

Comment: As I understand, EntityGraph only tells the Provider that before it returns the object, all data specified via the graph should be populated .i.e there would be 0 instances of LazyLoading when you "walk through" the returned object. Querying using EntityGraph does NOT make it mandatory for the provider to fetch everything is a single query.  If that were the case, all EntityGraph queries would generate a single SQL query.

Comment: Would you mind adding your mappings, entity graph and the generated sql? I would like to set a bounty on this question as I am also curious about the answer. But I don't believe experienced users will into it  without having a test case which they could easily setup for tests.

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this ever? It's been years since and the issue is still there.